# Add values of grouped dictionary elements based on keys swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, struct

I have an array of Offering called "offerings". I have grouped the array as shown below.

```
let groupedBonds = Dictionary(grouping: data.offerings) { (Offering) -> String in
            return Offering.company
        }

public struct Offering: Codable {
    public let company: String
    public let amount: Int
    public let location: String
}
```

The keys of the dictionary are the `companies -> ["ABCD", "EFGH", "IJKL", "MNOP"]`

I want to sum all the amounts of the respective companies. Please help me in achieving this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming what data.offerings equals to

```
let offerings = [
    Offering(company: "A", amount: 7, location: "a"),
    Offering(company: "A", amount: 4, location: "a"),
    Offering(company: "B", amount: 2, location: "a"),
    Offering(company: "C", amount: 3, location: "a"),
]
```

I want to sum all the amounts of the respective companies.

```
  let sumAmountByComany = offerings.reduce(into: [:]) { (result, offer)  in
         result[offer.company] = (result[offer.company] ?? 0 ) + offer.amount
    }
```

result

```
[
 "C": 3,
 "B": 2,
 "A": 11
]
```

Comment: You could also use `reduce(into:)`, which eliminates the need for a `var`

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to find the sum for all grouped arrays, you can use `mapValues` for this:

```
let amounts = groupedBonds.mapValues { $0.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.amount} }
```

`amounts` will be a dictionary having the same keys as `groupedBonds` (the company name in this case), but having as values the result of the transformation closure, which, coincidently or not, computes the sum for every array.